# Maven couldn't find jars from .m2/repository

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am making clone of project using mercurial plugin.
But, when I am going to build project following error occurred.

```
    9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-core:jar:1.31.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.jrobin:jrobin:jar:1.5.9:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.7.Final:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.7.Final:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:3.6.7.Final:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.4:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.17:runtime
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:2.0.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:runtime
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:jar:5.5.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.activemq:kahadb:jar:5.5.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:jar:1.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.1.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.7:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:jar:5.5.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:jar:1.2.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-io:jar:1.2.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.5.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.jscience:jscience:jar:4.3.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.11:runtime
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.5:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.5:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.gavaghan:geodesy:jar:0.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:runtime
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:3.7:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.0:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.9:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.2:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.9:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.15:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.8:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.7.1:test
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact opensymphony:sitemesh:jar:2.4.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.12:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact org.opensymphony.quartz:quartz-all:jar:1.6.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:10 PM IST: Missing artifact commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
9/4/12 12:53:15 PM IST: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
9/4/12 12:53:41 PM IST: [WARN] The POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.7.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
9/4/12 12:53:41 PM IST: [WARN] The POM for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
9/4/12 12:53:41 PM IST: [WARN] The POM for org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
9/4/12 12:53:41 PM IST: [WARN] The POM for org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:jar:5.5.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
9/4/12 12:53:41 PM IST: [WARN] The POM for org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:jar:1.2.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
9/4/12 12:53:41 PM IST: [WARN] The POM for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

I am given path of repository into properties->maven->user settings, but still its not resolved.

Any suggestions?

Comment: those jars exist in your local maven repo ?

Comment: Please post your Maven `settings.xml` file.

Comment: Have you tried to run mvn on console without eclipse etc. just mvn clean package ?

Comment: Maybe Maven cannot connect to a central repository to get the artifacts (check Proxy / Firewall), or it was unable once, and is now in the "Dont check again" mode. (Try -U to force an update of dependencies if you think you resolved that problem).

Comment: @JigarJoshi yes these are exist.

Comment: @DuncanJones I dont have any settings.xml into .m2 folder. But without that my previous project was working fine.

Comment: what OS are you using? If you can check the `.m2` folder then see if the `archetype` has put the required jar files in the local repo or try using `mvn generate` and select any archetype of your choice by number. If you are interested in creating your `own archetype` then tell.

Answer (score 2):

check settings in `%M2_HOME%\conf\settings.xml`

```
<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
```

should be set on toy local repo
and profiles shuld be set on some repo

```
  <profiles>
     <profile>
     <id>myprofile</id>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>my-repo2</id>
         <name>your custom repo</name>
         <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>  
</profiles>
```

also activate this profile

```
<activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
```

Comment: Thanks of ur ans. I installed Maven Integration For Eclipse plugin. Is it not enough?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, but I think maven is requared for this plugin. And this plugin is using settings.xml from maven

Comment: in my case %M2_HOME%\conf\settings.xml, proxy settings has changed, and it worked for me. No matter how many times I do it. I forget to change the expired proxy.